# Remove Duplicate Values - Using Data In 2 Columns & Removing Lowest Value

Tags: vba, excel

I have duplicate values in column E. Column D has numbers in. Using the two columns, I need to find duplicates in column E and remove the ones with the lowest number from the results.

I have been trying the following code, which I found online, but am unsure which values need changing to make it work for my document. Row 1 has column titles in it. Also when running the following code, I receive an error message.

```
Sub remdup()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, LR As Long, i As Long, LC As Integer
    LR = Cells(Rows.Count, “A”).End(xlUp).Row
    LC = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LR, LC)).Sort Key1:=Cells(1, 8), Order1:=xlDescending, _
    Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
    For i = LR To 2 Step -1
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns(1), Cells(i, 1).Value) > 1 Then Rows(i).Delete
    Next i
    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LR, LC)).Sort Key1:=Cells(1, 1), Order1:=xlDescending, _
    Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
End Sub
```

Comment: You are using a lot of direct cell addressing which is good but you are not specifying the parent worksheet which can be ambiguous (aka Bad). Why declare `ws As Worksheet` if you aren't going to use it?

Comment: @Jeeped I've got the code from another forum, but the post was a few years old. I'm pretty new to Excel macros, hence needing some help - whether it's re-writing the existing code or writing it from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added a `With ... End With` block that will allow you to assign the parent worksheet to all of the cell references.

The `.RemoveDuplicates` command is vastly superior to walking through the rows and deleting them if the count is greater than 1. Remove Duplicates always removes from the bottom up so as long as the data has been sorted on column D in a descending manner, you should be OK.

```
Sub remdup()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, LR As Long, LC As Integer

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")    '<< change this to the name of the worksheet
    With ws
        LR = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        LC = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        With .Cells(1, 1).Resize(LR, LC)
            .Sort Key1:=.Columns(4), Order1:=xlDescending, _
                Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
            .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=5, Header:=xlYes
            .Sort Key1:=.Columns(1), Order1:=xlDescending, _
                Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
        End With
    End With
    Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```

Finally, I have assumed that you actually *have* a header row. There really isn't any reason to use `xlGuess`. Either you have one or not.

Comment: thanks for the help. So that should remove the whole row for the duplicate item it's removing?

Comment: @JoshPotts - It will remove the row from column A to the last used column in row 1.

Comment: Well done & nicely put together! +1 I would've used the same approach: sort - remove duplicates - sort :)